# Why may one not make a business out of hunting wild animals?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, business, maseches-sheviis

Sheviis 7:4:

> צָדֵי חַיָּה עוֹפוֹת וְדָגִים שֶׁנִּזְדַּמְּנוּ לָהֶם מִינִים טְמֵאִין, מֻתָּרִים לְמָכְרָן. רַבִּי יְהוּדָה אוֹמֵר, אַף מִי שֶׁנִּתְמַנָּה לוֹ לְפִי דַרְכּוֹ, לוֹקֵחַ וּמוֹכֵר, וּבִלְבַד שֶׁלֹּא תְהֵא אֻמָּנוּתוֹ בְכָךְ. וַחֲכָמִים אוֹסְרִין:
>
> Hunters of wild animals, birds, and fish who happened across a non-kosher animal may sell them. R’ Yehudah says, even one who came across one on his way may take it and sell it, provides that this is not his business. And the Chachamim prohibit [this latter case of R’ Yehudah].

Explains the Bartenura (on the Tanna Kamma):

> דהא כתיב גבי נבלה (דברים יד) או מכור לנכרי הא לא אסרה תורה אלא לקיימן לעשות בהן סחורה אבל בנזדמן מותר:
>
> The passuk says regarding carcasses (Devarim 14): “Or to sell them to a non-Jew.” The Torah only forbade keeping them to do business with them, but happening upon them is permitted.

What is the reason behind this derasha? Is there a reason that one may not sell non-kosher animals beyond a gezeiras hakasuv?

Comment: it is dirabonon

Comment: @hazoriz I brought you a passuk, and you tell me it’s d’Rabbanan?!

Comment: if the animals are kosher he can (even if non kosher ones also get trapped)

Comment: @hazoriz Again, the case is doing business specifically with non-kosher animals - the case of happening upon non-kosher animals is discussed in the remainder of the Mishnah.

Comment: it seems you are right see sif 2 http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14242&pgnum=580

Comment: IIRC it's a safeguard against coming to eat them, which is why one may do business with animals that are not commonly eaten, like horses. Kitzur SA 64: כָּל דָּבָר שֶׁאָסוּר מִן הַתּוֹרָה בַּאֲכִילָה, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוּא מֻתָּר בַּהֲנָאָה, אִם הוּא דָּבָר הַמְיֻחָד לְמַאֲכָל, אָסוּר לַעֲשׂוֹת בּוֹ סְחוֹרָה אוֹ לְהַלְווֹת עָלָיו. וַאֲפִלּוּ לִקְנֹתוֹ לְהַאֲכִילוֹ לְפוֹעֲלוֹ אֵינוֹ יְהוּדִי, אָסוּר. אֲבָל דָּבָר שֶׁאֵינוֹ עוֹמֵד לַאֲכִילָה, כְּגוֹן סוּסִים וַחֲמוֹרִים, מֻתָּר לַעֲשׂוֹת בָּהֶם סְחוֹרָה.

Comment: @DannySchoemann How can we say that a passuk is coming as a safeguard?

Comment: @DonielF - the pasuk isn't saying anything; Chazal interpret it as such, probably based on context or mesora - though the "safeguard" part may be a retro-fit for the law.